# how javascript assign reference value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I am learning react and i was using `react-router-dom` library to change the routes of the project. So i added  from the library and added history to it. And added `createBrowserHistory` from npm package `history`.

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
```

But it was not changing the routes and was generating a warning.

```
You cannot change <Router history>
```

then i changed it to and then passed in Router

```
const history = createBrowserHistory()
<Router history={history}>
```

Passing the browser history to a variable worked. Why was this happening? Is this some concept of Javascript ?

Comment: Your second example doesn't do what you say it does. Have you made a typo?

Comment: Is this the createBrowserHistory from the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/history ?

Comment: Try using  <Router history={createBrowserHistory({})}> this. and use import statement as 

import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think main problem here could be related to the scope of variable. While you creating object inside of jsx it will be stored inside of Router component and maybe react needs to have it accessible outside of it. (For example when history changes react knows that it should rerender component)

But anyway if you are beginner you don't need to use Router component, check BrowserRouter https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route